# Trouble running a tomcat server on a spring project

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

So I'm really bad with STS and java in general, so here I'm trying to get my group project (string project) in STS, add it to a Tomcat 7 server, and run it, but I always end up with the same error in console:

```
12 juin 2015 18:18:44 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ATTENTION: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:easypark' did not find a matching property.
12 juin 2015 18:18:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.62
12 juin 2015 18:18:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          May 7 2015 17:14:55 UTC
12 juin 2015 18:18:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.62.0
12 juin 2015 18:18:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
12 juin 2015 18:18:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
12 juin 2015 18:18:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
12 juin 2015 18:18:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre6
12 juin 2015 18:18:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.6.0_45-b06
12 juin 2015 18:18:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Sun Microsystems Inc.
12 juin 2015 18:18:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\Docs\Boulot\techno web\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
12 juin 2015 18:18:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         D:\Docs\Boulot\techno web\apache-tomcat-7.0.62\apache-tomcat-7.0.62
12 juin 2015 18:18:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\Docs\Boulot\techno
12 juin 2015 18:18:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: web\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
12 juin 2015 18:18:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\Docs\Boulot\techno
12 juin 2015 18:18:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: web\apache-tomcat-7.0.62\apache-tomcat-7.0.62
12 juin 2015 18:18:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\Docs\Boulot\techno
12 juin 2015 18:18:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: web\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
12 juin 2015 18:18:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\Docs\Boulot\techno
12 juin 2015 18:18:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: web\apache-tomcat-7.0.62\apache-tomcat-7.0.62\endorsed
12 juin 2015 18:18:45 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
12 juin 2015 18:18:45 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;.
12 juin 2015 18:18:47 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
12 juin 2015 18:18:47 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
12 juin 2015 18:18:47 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 4908 ms
12 juin 2015 18:18:47 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Démarrage du service Catalina
12 juin 2015 18:18:47 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.62
12 juin 2015 18:18:48 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci onStartup
INFO: JSR 356 WebSocket (Java WebSocket 1.1) support is not available when running on Java 6. To suppress this message, run Tomcat on Java 7, remove the WebSocket JARs from $CATALINA_HOME/lib or add the WebSocket JARs to the tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip property in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties. Note that the deprecated Tomcat 7 WebSocket API will be available. 
12 juin 2015 18:18:48 org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [251] milliseconds.
12 juin 2015 18:18:49 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\Docs\Boulot\techno web\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\easypark\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-2.5.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
12 juin 2015 18:18:49 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\Docs\Boulot\techno web\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\easypark\WEB-INF\lib\jsp-api-2.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
12 juin 2015 18:18:50 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/easypark]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/easypark]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/FatalBeanException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:892)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5416)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 29 more
12 juin 2015 18:18:50 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
12 juin 2015 18:18:50 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
GRAVE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
12 juin 2015 18:18:50 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
12 juin 2015 18:18:50 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
12 juin 2015 18:18:50 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Arrêt du service Catalina
12 juin 2015 18:18:50 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
12 juin 2015 18:18:50 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

It's weird because I got the same configuration they have, and it works for them.
Any help would be gladly welcome. If you need more info, just ask me, because I don't know what to send you...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add spring beans dependency to your maven.
You could get more info here:
http://spring.io/blog/2009/12/02/obtaining-spring-3-artifacts-with-maven/

Answer (score 0):

`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/FatalBeanException`

Please check if you have the necessary Spring specific dependent libraries available for the deployed Tomcat application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Turns out I was missing some...

I did what they said there, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921641/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-beans-factory-nouniquebeande

And then add manually the jar files missing for Maven dependencies!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Case of missing dependency I guess.Check if your tomcat's WEB-INF/lib contains the jar which have FatalBeanException class.For jars having this class you can check here [FatalBeanException jars](http://grepcode.com/search/?query=FatalBeanException)